# Cookie not being set but database is changed

Tags: php, jquery, database, cookies

I'm using jQuery for users voting articles up/down. When the user votes a cookie is set so the user can only vote an article once (without refreshing cookies). This works fine, except when the user votes and refreshes the page instantly after voting:

jQuery:

```
$.post('vote.php',{id:id,field:field},function(){
// change button graphics
});
```

PHP:

```
setcookie(User::$cookieStart . User::$db_fields[$field_index], 
        $cookie . ':' . $id, time()+60*60*24*30,'/'); 
// This calls a function that effects the db
User::actionArticleTable($id,$field_index,1);
```

When the user refreshes, the cookie is **not** set but the **mysql-info is changed**, even though the db code is after the cookie code.

Comment: What if I delete the cookie? I can still vote multiple times. I recommand you to save votes for each user in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are just header items in HTML pages, so no change in cookies occurs until the vote.php page is loaded. If the user refreshes the main page before the vote.php page has returned no cookie is set. The cookie is fine for next time users comes on this page, but if you want to block the voting instantly consider setting the cookie by javascript.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am taking care of what you are mentioning. The user can not vote again on that ID until that action is done. Do you suggest that I have two jQuery functions, first change the cookie and after that is done, then perform the db-action?

Comment: I think if you set the cookie in js it will be available instantly